# Swift CoreData -- Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'Int16'

Tags: ios, core-data

I declared a CoreData entity Address with a 'zip' attribute of type Int16.

Problem is, when I assign an integer to that attribute:

```
address?.zip = Int(zipField.text!)
```

I get an error saying Cannot assign value of type Int to type Int16. Makes sense (I guess).

Problem is, when I try casting that int to an Int16, XCode still blows up on me:

```
let zip:Int? = Int(zipField.text!)
if zip != nil {
    let zip16 = Int16(zip!)
}
```

It's that line where I convert the integer that causes XCode to crash. I am not really seeing any information in the error message, so I'm not sure what to try.

In general, should I be using Int64 because of the operating system of these phones?

Comment: Be specific - add the exact error message to you question. You should probably also add the crash log in case it has useful information. Also, are you sure the value in `zip` can be represented as an `Int16` and is not too large?

Comment: @RoboticCat now that you mention it, the number *is* too large for an Int16.. oops. Thanks!

Comment: No problem.  You should also look at @DaveWeston answer for how to structure your code because your code does not take advantage of Swift's features that minimise crashes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should banish all `!`s from your code. That just tells the compiler "crash here if I do something wrong":

```
if let str = zipField.text,
    let zip = Int16(str) {
    address?.zip = zip
}
```

Also, you should read about Swift's `guard` statement because there's no point in running any of that code if you don't have an address. Something like:

```
guard let addr = address else { return }
addr.zip = 90210
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
address?.zip = Int16(zipField.text!)
```

And in document of structure `Int16`, about `init?(String, radix: Int)`,there is the following discussion:

> If text does not match the regular expression “[+-]?[0-9a-zA-Z]+”, or the value it denotes in the given radix is not representable, the result is nil.

So you should make sure the text is valid in order to convert.